# How can I tell a multiclass classifier that 2 categories are closely related and therefore misclassification between them should not be penalised?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, multiclass-classification

I have a multiclass classification problem for an e-commerce website, with close to 2000 categories. Categories are across fashion, electronics, appliances etc., and some of these categories are closely related to each other. For example, consider the pairs: 
[electric mixer, food processor]
[Lip gloss, lipstick] etc. 
I am training a multiclass one-vs-all classifier for this. My question is, how do I pass on this information to the classifier that it is okay to misclassify among closely related pairs?

Comment: Can I ask you a question back? Why you don't define it upfront and summarize both categories?

Answer (score 0):

To do so you have to specify it when you write a custom loss function. This is the same philosophy as trying to apply different weights on classes.

I found this code that could work on your case (using keras):
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2115

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don’t want to penalize this confusion at all, it is the same as combine them together as one class.
2. Why do you train one-vs-all classifier? In most of the cases it is better to use multi class classifier.
3. You can chain the results of the high level classifier (that predicts the category) with a few low level classifiers to predict the specific sub category)